# Unlock manual garage door from back of lock mechanism

Tags: garage-door

I can get into the garage and have access to back of lock mechanism.  Is there away to unlock the door from the back of the lock?
Thanks!

Comment: A picture will help, but if the spring loaded cable type, just pull on the two cables to unlock.

Comment: Both my dad's an my garage doors could be unlocked from the inside by turning a knob. Please post a picture of the back of your garage door lock.

Comment: Yes there is. But we don't know how to unlock yours without more info.

Comment: If nothing else works, I find a sledge hammer is good at unlocking most doors.  Might need a new lock/door.

Answer (score 0):

Most locks won't allow you to turn the handle from inside, the handle on the outside connects to a plate inside which often pulls and pushes two long rods which run to the side of the frame.
However, it's often possible to dismount some supports holding the rods and find enough slack to pull the rods out of their holes/brackets in the frame.

Comment: I have never seen a garage door that could not be readiy unlocked from the inside. This is a safety requirement. Of course, if the chains or rods that retract the locking pins/tabs were removed, then twisting the center handle would not retract them.